# _really_ disable GtkTreeView searching

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

How do I really disable gtk treeview interactive search? The [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html) say to `set_enable_search(False)`, but if I do this, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> still causes an annoying search pop-up to appear. Connecting to `start-interactive-search` and returning `True` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pygtk docs don't state this, but the [C docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-search-column) do:

```
gtk_tree_view_set_search_column (GtkTreeView *tree_view, gint column)

column :
    the column of the model to search in, or -1 to disable searching
```

Passing `-1` for the column really disables searching.

Comment: Link is rotten.  I think you mean gtk_tree_view_set_search_column(-1), as this seems to work.