# Disable the interactive-search popup of GtkTreeView

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, gtktreeview

Typing `Ctrl-F` on a GtkTreeView enables a popup where a search-term can be inserted.
I want to disable this popup, since I want to use `Ctrl-F` for another purpose. 
Also, the amount of data displayed is quite large, so typing something in the popup freezes the whole application for a few seconds.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577224/really-disable-gtktreeview-searching) does not answer the question, since the docs of `gtk_tree_view_set_enable_search()` state:

```
Note that even if this is FALSE, the user can still
initiate a search using the “start-   interactive-search” key binding.
```

I tried the following without any noticeable effect:

- `gtk_treeview_set_enable_search(false)`
- `gtk_treeview_set_search_column(-1)`
- connecting to `start-interactive-search` and return `True` for "handled!".

Im using Gtk+-3.12.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Either use `gtk_binding_entry_remove()` to unbind `Ctrl-F` on the TreeView, or use
something along the following lines:

```
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_data("""
    @binding-set unbind_search { unbind "<Control>f"; }
    GtkTreeView { gtk-key-bindings: unbind_search; }
""".encode('utf-8'))
context = Gtk.StyleContext()
context.add_provider_for_screen(
    Gdk.Screen.get_default(), css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER
)
```